# Rails redirection to show when redirected to other action in same class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

My Task is to submit a form to `place_order` action inside `Checkout` controller.
This is how I wrote form in my view file i.e

```
<%= form_for (@order), url: {action: "place_order"} do |f| %>
```

It does reach inside this method and as I save object i want to `redirect` to some other method in the same class. This method name is `thank_you`. My code looks like this inside `place_order` method

```
if @order.save
  redirect_to :action => 'thank_you'
else
  ...
end
```

But it redirects to show method of this class. If I change redirect to other class, it redirects fine but on other action of same `controller`, it always redirects to `show`.

Here is how I defined my routes

```
resources  :checkout
resources  :photos
devise_for :users
resources  :carts

post  'checkout/place_order'
match 'checkout/thank_you', to: 'checkout#thank_you', via: [:get]
```

I need some expert opinion on this. Please help.

Comment: Are you sure? please verify once and make sure. I doubt because if `save` returns `true` then it must redirect to `thank_you` action.

Comment: Yes i am quite sure. I had checked it many times before posting question here and the answer below has solved it. Thanks for looking at my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move your `thank_you` route above `resources  :checkout`.

From [Rails guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html):

> Rails routes are matched in the order they are specified, so if you
>   have a resources :photos above a get 'photos/poll' the show action's
>   route for the resources line will be matched before the get line. To
>   fix this, move the get line above the resources line so that it is
>   matched first.

Comment: Great answer Nitish; nice observation. Keep up